# NodeJs Mongoose Promise then/catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

Faced an issue with Mongoose promises

```
MyModel.find().then((data)=> Promise.reject())
       .catch(()=>console.log('first catch'))
       .then(()=>console.log('ok'))
       .catch(()=>console.log('second catch'));
```

after the execution I get

```
first catch
second catch
```

But if I do it with only native Promises:

```
Promise.reject()
       .catch(()=>console.log('first catch'))
       .then(()=>console.log('ok'))
       .catch(()=>console.log('second catch'));
```

after the execution I get

```
first catch
ok
```

that is ok in terms of Promise [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

It seems that Mongoose uses own `promise implementation`

I have found that I can solve that by doing the following

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { MyModel.find().then((data) => reject()) })
       .catch(()=>console.log('first catch'))
       .then(()=>console.log('ok')
       .catch(()=>console.log('second catch'));
```

It works as it should according the docs:

```
first catch
ok
```

Any suggestion how to work with that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose uses Promises/A+ conformant promises. For backwards compatibility, Mongoose 4 returns `mpromise` promises by default.

If you want to use advanced promise features, you should use library like bluebird or native ES6 promises. To do that just set `mongoose.Promise` to your favorite ES6-style promise constructor and mongoose will use it:

```
require('mongoose').Promise = Promise;
// or
require('mongoose').Promise = require('bluebird');
```

[Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use of q library for promises.
"q": "^1.4.1"
q is the most populated library for java script promises.so we can use multiple promises result together.

```
var Q = require('q');

var promises= Q.all([
  Model.find(),
  Model2.find(),
  Model3.find()
]);

promises.then(function(data) {
  //console.log(data[0]);
  //console.log(data[1]);
  //console.log(data[2]);
});

promises.then(null, function(err) {
});
```